# TeamCity - Unable to find version '6.1.3' of package 'EntityFramework'

Tags: msbuild, nuget, teamcity

I have configured Nuget restore Team City build step to restore all the nugget dependencies before solution build.

The Nuget restore build step looks like following

[image]

When I run the build I get following error.

```
[10:31:38][restore] JetBrains TeamCity NuGet Runner 8.0.46654.9
[10:31:38][restore] Registered additional extensions from paths: C:\BuildAgent\plugins\nuget-agent\bin\plugins-2.5
[10:31:38][restore] Starting NuGet.exe 2.7.41115.310 from C:\BuildAgent\tools\NuGet.CommandLine.2.7.3\tools\NuGet.exe
[10:31:43][restore] Unable to find version '6.1.3' of package 'EntityFramework'.
[10:31:43][restore] Process exited with code 1
[10:31:43][restore] Process exited with code 1
```

I don't know what's wrong here.

The nuget package EF 6.1.3 is available at nuget.org.

Is it something that nuget.org isn't accessible by my build agents?
Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the NuGet.exe version to the latest fixed my problem.